# pass arguments from script to script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script to delete files older than x mins/days.

```
find $1 -type f -mmin +$2 -exec rm -f {} \; (name is test2.sh)
```

I need to pass arguments to `test2.sh` from another script `test3.sh` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the parameter expansions in `test2.sh` are correctly quoted as

```
find "$1" -type f -mmin +"$2" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

then `test3.sh` might have a call to `test2.sh` like this:

```
test2.sh "some file name" 5
```

`$1` in `test2.sh` will expand to the string `some file name` and `$2` will expand to `5`.

This is assuming that `test2.sh` is located in a directory that is listed in the `PATH` variable of `test3.sh`.  If not, use a full path (absolute or relative), for example:

```
./test2.sh "some file name" 5
```

It also assumes that `test2.sh` has first been made executable with `chmod +x test2.sh` and that it has a correct `#!`-line.

---

After clarification in comment below:

The `test3.sh` script could do (assuming it's a `bash` script):

```
read -p 'Enter directory name: ' dirname
read -p 'Enter number of days: ' days

minutes=$(( days * 60 * 24 ))

./test2.sh "$dirname" "$minutes"
```

The next step would be to validate the user's input so that `$days` is an actual integer and so that `$dirname` is a valid name of a directory.

If it's not `bash` but `sh`:

```
printf 'Enter directory name: '
read -r dirname

(etc.)
```

---

Most implementations of `find` also have `-delete`:

```
find "$1" -type f -mmin +"$2" -delete
```

Comment: I know how my script works. But I need script test3.sh in which we have echo "Enter directory:" read directory and then days , and then pass the to that test2.sh script

Comment: @Itso I've update my answer.

Comment: I get this error: find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mmin'

Comment: @Itso Make sure your quoting is correct. You might get this if you have `find ... -mmin +"$2 -exec ...` maybe?

Comment: @ltso that happens if the argument following `-mmin` is empty (no `+`, no value), i.e. `find ... -mmin -exec rm -f {} \;`. But as Kusalananda says, you should really be using `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`. Check your single and double quoting for your `find` command. AND for the script `test3.sh`.